X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff and missing content-type
We have a web server which is returning a X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff but no content-type for a pptx file.
This results in Firefox of appearently defaulting to a content-type of application/octet-stream
while Chrome is appearenlty defaulting to a content-type of text/plain and trying to display the file.
This being said i cant seem to find a reference that would confirm this obseration.
So can someone confirm that in absence of a correct content-type header but with a header of "X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff", then browser might behave erraticly?
tx
if i remove the X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff then both browser behave the same and try to download the file.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
